# Wordpress https:// broken home page and admin area

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

My wordpress website is using cloudfare and I desided to make my website from http:// -> https://

I installed Wordpress HTTPS and SSL Insecure Content Fixer plugins and changed URLs in Settings -> General (from http:// to https://)

This made my home page & admin area show "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". ALL other pages work great with the green https:// bar

I tried make things which I found on google: adding lines to wp-config.php or .htaccess  But either it doesn't change anythin or it breaks other pages too.

Website is hosted on Ubuntu server.

P.S. Only if I replace https:// to http:// (through the mysql) I can access admin area and home page BUT they load without css styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your wp-config.php (before $table_prefix = 'wp_'; line) and it will work.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) 
  $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

The first block "tells" PHP that your website is already using https. (you need to tell it because it is not local apache https, but 3rd party out-server SSL). Second one forces wp-admin always use SSL.

Comment: You are a rockstar!